# OpenWebRTC test-uri No decoder available for type audio/mpeg and owr_video_renderer_get_element assertion

Tags: audio, video, webrtc, gstreamer

Compiled the OpenWebRTC, so it builds its own GStreamer. The `test-send-receive` worked fine for audio. Ubuntu 15.04.

Launching the `test-uri` test program like that:

```
export PATH=/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib
export GST_PLUGIN_PATH_1_0=/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib/gstreamer-1.0/

test-uri file://$HOME/Videos/small.mp4
```

The file is:

http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

The error:

```
==== Warning message start ====
Warning in element uridecodebin-1.
Warning: No decoder available for type 'audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, level=(string)2, base-profile=(string)lc, profile=(string)lc, codec_data=(buffer)1188, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)1'.
Debugging info: gsturidecodebin.c(939): unknown_type_cb (): /GstPipeline:uri-source-agent-1/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin-1
==== Warning message stop ====
Got "video stream, id: 0" source!
**
ERROR:owr_video_renderer.c:314:owr_video_renderer_get_element: assertion failed: (flip)
```

The `gst-launch-1.0` plays this file fine with audio and video on GStreamer that comes with the OS. But the one in the `/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib/gstreamer-1.0/` doesn't play audio.

How to fix at least the audio warning in the GStreamer built by OpenWebRTC? And then that fatal video renderer error.